# Limit of sum/difference condition which are not being followed here

Tags: calculus, limits

This was given as an example in a book : If $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)+g(x)]=2$$ and
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)-g(x)]=1,$$ then find the value of $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) g(x)$$

Solution :  $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)+g(x)]=2$$
or $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)+\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=2$$ $\tag{1}$
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow a}[f(x)-g(x)]=1$$
or $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)-\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=1$$ $\tag{2}$
Adding (1) and (2),
$$2 \lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=3$$ or $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\frac{3}{2}$$
Subtracting (2) from (1),
$$2 \lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x) \neq 1$$ or $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$
or $$\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) g(x)=\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=\frac{3}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

> My query is that isnt the lim of sum = individual limits sum only when we  already know that limit of individual sum  exists ? Here we actually dont know if it actually exists or not so shouldnt this method is totally wrong ?

Comment: The individual limits are for $u(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and $v(x) = f(x)-g(x)$. Those limits are known to exist, so the limits for $u(x)+v(x)$ and $u(x)-v(x)$ also exist. Or is that not your question?

Comment: Okay yeah thats right , but the first step in their solution was they wrote lim(sum) = lim(invidual) + limit (indi) without saying anything isnt ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer I would agree that their approach is slightly imprecise and does rely on the limits existing without actually proving it, Brian's comment indicates a slightly improved version of their logic which works out equivalently but avoids this minor issue

Comment: Assuming you're not paraphrasing, I would agree that they went about it a little sloppily, but the result still obtains. To be honest, it might help if you broke up the typesetting a little; it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: Understood thanks @StephenDonovan Brian Tung

Comment: This solution is difficult to read, so here's some MathJax tips: to create display maths (i.e. maths shown on its own line, centred, in display mode), surround your code in `$$` instead of just  `$`. While in display mode, you can use the `\tag` command to tag your equations: i.e. to label them things like $(1)$ and $(2)$. For example, `$$2f(x) = (f(x) + g(x)) + (f(x) - g(x)) \tag{1}$$` produces:$$2f(x) = (f(x) + g(x)) + (f(x) - g(x)) \tag{1}$$

Comment: Did it next time onwards too i will try doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the way it is written is slightly problematic. That $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+g(x)$ exists doesn't mean that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist. However, there is no actual reason to split the limits and try writing
\begin{align*}
\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)+\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=2\\
\lim _{x \rightarrow a} f(x)-\lim _{x \rightarrow a} g(x)=1
\end{align*}
as they have. Instead, work directly with
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+g(x)=2\\
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)-g(x)=1
\end{align*}
and add these two together (as the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits), and get
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)+g(x)+f(x)-g(x)=3$$
i.e.
$$\lim_{x\to a} 2f(x)=3$$
and indeed $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists, while no unjustified splitting of limits has occurred.